# Logstash Date Filter

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, grok

I have a log file which has date in following format

```
"respHdr":{"date":"Tue,%2008%20Jul%202014%2022:08:18%20GMT","expires":"Tue,%2008%20Jul%202014%2022:08:18%20GMT"}
```

How to parse the given date format using logstash Date filter?

Comment: Can  you explain your log meaning?

Comment: You need to use grok filter fo this. Regarding the format,you can use Grok debugger(https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) in order to see whether your logstash grok filter is working fine or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your log is in JSON format with URLEncoded values in the date field, so the first thing you need to do is add `codec=>json` to your `input`, or `json { source => message }`.

After you have things as events in Logstash, you'll want to decode the date fields:

```
urldecode { field => 'respHdr.date' }
urldecode { field => 'respHdr.expires' }
```

And then finally parse the dates in those fields:

```
date {
  target => '@timestamp'
  match => [ 'respHdr.date', 'WHATEVER_FORMAT_THAT_DATE_IS' ]
}
date {
  target => 'expires'
  match => [ 'respHdr.expires', 'WHATEVER_FORMAT_THAT_DATE_IS' ]
}
```

You'll need to consult [logstash date documentation](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/date) to figure out what format that date is.